# Getting selected listbox items values to display in another listbox using vb 2008

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a form with a 2 listboxes. Here, listbox1 is populated with names of actors and actresses. If a name is selected from listbox1, listbox2 should show the title(s) of movie(s) where that name is involved. If another name is selected, listbox2 will show title(s) of movie(s) that 2 name is involved.

```
Call Connect()
    With Me
        STRSQL = "select mTitle from selectmovie where cName = '" & lstNames.SelectedItem & "'"
        Try
            myCmd.Connection = myConn
            myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
            myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
            If (myReader.Read()) Then
                myReader.Close()
                myAdptr.SelectCommand = myCmd
                myAdptr.Fill(myDataTable)
                lstTitle.DisplayMember = "mTitle"
                lstTitle.ValueMember = "mTitle"

                If myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
                        lstTitle.Items.Add(myDataTable.Rows(i)("mTitle"))
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End With
```

There's no error. When I select 1 item the result is correct but it leaves many space..here the screen shot of my form: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92925726@N06/8445945758/in/photostream/

The output becomes worse when I selected actor3: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92925726@N06/8445945724/in/photostream/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that you do not clear your `lstTitle` control before re-loading it with the new selection.  Therefore, each time you select a new name, it will add all the titles for that name to the existing list of titles that are already loaded.  Also, instead of using an integer to iterate all the indexes, it is easier to just use a `For Each` loop:

```
lstTitle.Items.Clear()
For Each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
    lstTitle.Items.Add(row("mTitle"))
Next
```

However, I must also mention that you really should also be using a parameter in your query rather than dynamically building the SQL statement like that, for instance:

```
myCmd.CommandText = "select mTitle from selectmovie where cName = @name"
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", lstNames.SelectedItem)
```

To select all the movies where all of the multiple selected actors are involved, you would need to add an additional condition to your where clause for each actor, for instance:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
builder.Append("select distinct mTitle from selectmovie where ")
For i As Integer = 0 to lstNames.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    Dim parameterName As String = "@name" & i.ToString()
    If i <> 0 Then
        builder.Append("and ")
    End If
    builder.Append(parameterName)
    builder.Append(" in (select cName from selectmovie where mTitle = m.mTitle) ")
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, lstNames.SelectedItems(i))
Next
myCmd.CommandText = builder.ToString()
```

Comment: thanks Steven, I followed your suggestion but still getting the same result: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92925726@N06/8445945758/in/photostream except the part that when I select another item it shows the list properly now. what could be the problem sir?

Comment: So it only shows those blank ones when actor 1 is selected?  If so, are you sure those blank items aren't actually in the DB?

Comment: no they're not sir..I stored it in the database like this: http://s1341.beta.photobucket.com/user/kumsay/media/data_zps3b8addfb.png.html

Comment: I mean yes, the problem are those blank that appears when actor1 is selected, but those blank are not on the database sir. Actually, it appears during the first selected item so even if I chose actor5 first, its still the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you set `myDataTable` to a new `DataTable` object each time, or do you just set that once and keep re-using it?  If it's the latter, it's possible that it already contains some initial blank rows before it gets to loading the first time.

Comment: Oh my God!,its working perfectly now. Thank you very much sir, your a lifesaver..God bless :)

Comment: @VBeginner, don't forget to acknoledge his lifesaving skills by clicking the checkmark next to his answer.

Comment: thanks for the reminder Doug. I still have another question, sorry for late observation, its working really good now but is it possible that when I chose an item (ex. actor2) it will show the movies that actor2 is involved and when I select another one, say actor4, it will show only the movies where actor 2 and 4 is involved, and so on?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but it's a bit more complicated.  In that case, I would recommend setting the `lstNames.SelectionMode` property to single or multi-extended mode.  Then you would need to loop through all the `lstNames.SelectedItems` to build a sql command with a dynamic number of parameters, for instance: `select mTitle from selectmovie where cName in (@name1, @name2, @name3)`.

Comment: Nope, scratch that.  I thought you said you wanted all the movies where it had either of those names.  If you only want ones where both actors are in it, you'd need to add a JOIN clause for each additional name.

Comment: oh..I'm really sorry sir I didn't noticed first your updated answer earlier. I still built the SQL statement dynamically, I tried to use the parameter before but I keep on getting an error after the first selection. It says "Parameter 'name' has already been defined" but when I used my first SQL statement it works with no error. So in your updated answer sir, I tried but can't figure out how can I replace the parameter '@name'. Please help me sir, why did I get error when I used the parameter?..

Comment: Are you creating a new command each time you execute a command or are you reusing the command object?  I'm guessing that you are reusing the command object and therefore it still contains the parameters from the last time you used it.  If so, you shouldn't be doing it that way.  You should be creating a new command object for each command you need to execute.

Comment: command object..are you referring sir to the STRSQL that I used before as the command text? (forgive me, I'm not familiar with the terms)

Comment: I didn't use the 'STRSQL' string on that part anymore..I just used that string when I filled the 'lstNames' with values from the database then I used what you suggested above to use a parameter but I got that error..

Comment: I got it now sir, I can use the parameter :)..my problem now is I tried your last suggestion, if I'm not mistaken I should replaced the for each loop with that. When I run the program, it says 'index was outside the bounds of the array' but its now working the way I wanted it..how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Oops!  I forgot to subtract one from the count.  I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: oh my..i'm sorry too sir, scratch that part that "I should replace the for each loop" ^_^v..its now working perfectly!!,at last after 2 days I got it working now, of course it's because of u Mr. Doggart. Thank you very much for the help sir, you're really my lifesaver..God bless you more!! :D