# Get all listbox items in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm working on a Recipe library. I have a form with 3 listboxes (lstIngredient, lstSelected, lstRecipe) and a find button. lstIngredient is filled with ingredient names stored in the database.

When the user select (double-clicked) a name in the lstIngredient, it will be listed to the lstSelected. After that, when user clicked the find button, it will locate in the database what recipes uses those ingredients. The table in the database looks like this:

```
 id |   recipe   |   ingredient
 1  | spaghetti  |  tomato sause
 2  | spaghetti  |  cheese
 3  | spaghetti  |  hotdog
 4  |  burger    |  bread bun
 5  |  burger    |  burger patty
 6  |  burger    |  cheese
```

So here, say user selected `cheese`, `bread bun` and `hotdog` (note: these items are selected one by one), these will be listed in the lstSelected. When find button is clicked, the result should be `burger` and `spaghetti`. If you could notice, burger is the first item in the list..it's an example that the result in the lstRecipe should be depending on the number of occurrence of the ingredient selected. Here's what I have done:

```
Call Connect()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Try
        lstRecipe.Items.Clear()

        cmd.Connection = myConn
        cmd.CommandText = "select recipe from cook_book where ingredient = @item"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("item", lstSelected.Items)

        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
        If (myReader.Read()) Then
            myReader.Close()
            myAdptr.SelectCommand = cmd
            myAdptr.Fill(dt)
            lstRecipe.DisplayMember = "recipe"

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                lstRecipe.Items.Add(row("recipe"))
            Next
            Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
            builder.Append("select distinct recipe from cook_book where")
            For y As Integer = 0 To lstSelected.Items.Count - 1

                Dim parameterName As String = "@item" & y.ToString()
                If y <> 0 Then
                    builder.Append("and ")
                End If
                builder.Append(parameterName)
                builder.Append(" in (select ingredient from cook_book where recipe = i.recipe) ")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, lstSelected.Items(y))
            Next
            cmd.CommandText = builder.ToString()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cmd = Nothing
    myReader = Nothing
    myConn.Close()
    Call Disconnect()
```

The code is under the btnFind_Click event. I don't receive any error but it's not functioning the way that it should be. It only finds the last recipe of the last ingredient that the user selected.

Comment: what query you get after you debug?

Comment: This code is a real mess: First myReader and myCmd, where they come from, what is their purpose, what is the command text?. Second lstSelected.Items is a collection not a single value, you can't use it as value for a parameter. Third, the where clause in the stringbuilder is incomplete (miss the field part). Fourth, what is the i.recipe? Are you sure that this code doens't throw exception all over the place?

Comment: @AshReva : as a result, say I selected cheese and hotdog, the only recipe that shows in the lstRecipe is spaghetti..but if I chose hotdog first then cheese, spaghetti and burger will be the result.

Comment: @Steve : sorry sir, I just referred the code from here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695322/getting-selected-listbox-items-values-to-display-in-another-listbox-using-vb-200/14695822#14695822). I just added the lstSelected then made some changes in the code like from `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("item", lstSelected.SelectedItem)` to `lstSelected.Items`;`For y As Integer = 0 to lstSelected.SelectedItems.Count - 1` to `lstSelected.Items.Count - 1`;`myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, lstSelected.SelectedItems(y))` to `lstSelected.Items(y)`.

Comment: I thought it's okay if I do that but..obviously I'm wrong and I don't know what to do. Can you please correct me?